# React: Returning iterated list from a stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I run this code, I get the error:

> unexpected token, expected ,

All I am doing is calling a map method on an array:

```
const Available = ({prod}) => {
    let keys = Object.keys(prod)
    var filtered = keys.filter((item, index) => prod[item])
    return (
        {
            filtered.map((item, index) => {
            return <li><a>{item}</a></li>
        })
}
    )

}

Available.defaultProps = {
    Prod: {
        nuts: true,
        bolts: true,
        wiper: false,
        discbreak: true
    }
}

const Drop = (props) => {
    var style = {
        display: 'block'
    }
    if (props.isOpen) {
        return (
            <ul className="dropdown-menu" style={style}>
                <Available />
            </ul>
        )
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

I even tried changing 'Available' Component to as below.

```
const AvailableProducts = ({products}) => {
  debugger;
  let keys = Object.keys(products);
  var filtered = keys.filter((item,index)=>products[item]);

  filtered.map((item,index)=>{
    return <li><a>{item}</a></li>
  })
}
```

Now I end up getting error:

> A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Where am i doing wrong? Can someone help on this?

Comment: Try wrapping your `.map()` in a `div`

Comment: This is because your Available component return an array like this:

`[<li><a>{item}</a></li>, <li><a>{item}</a></li>, <li><a>{item}</a></li>]`

You have to return a react component or null.. example: 

`<div><li></li><li></li><li></li></div>`

Comment: Can any one explain,  From where prod value will come in this code -- const Available = ({prod}) => {

Comment: @MukulSharma: Its coming from propTypes, The syntax is new and its as per ES6. Its called as 'Destructing Assignment'. For more info, <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second code, you are not returning anything, thus react throws that "A valid React element ..." error. Since filtered is an array, you should return filtered variable inside the div and you should be able to see your component without errors.

```
const AvailableProducts = ({products}) => {
  debugger;
  let keys = Object.keys(products);
  var filtered = keys.filter((item,index)=>products[item]);

  filtered = filtered.map((item,index)=>{
    return <li><a>{item}</a></li>
  });
  return <div>{filtered}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const Available = ({prod}) => {
  let keys = Object.keys(prod);
  var filtered = keys.filter((item)=>prod[item]);
  return (
    <div>
      {filtered.map((item)=><li><a>{item}</a></li>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You should return a single, valid React component (or null).

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#render